# How to pass ConnectionString parameters with variables?

Tags: c#, connection-string

I have a ConnectionString and I want to pass it values (DataSource, Database, User ID, Password) with values from a .txt file and I need to read them, then pass them to the connectionString but I'm very confused how should I do this.

In my program I have a Helper Class to return the connectionString

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static string ConnectionString(string name)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

This is how I call the connectionString so I can access the database data

```
using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionString("Hotel")))
{
     connection.Execute($"INSERT INTO dbo.Registos_Cancelados(Nome, Telemovel, Data) VALUES(@Nome, @Telemovel, @Data)", new { Nome = nome, Telemovel = telemovel, Data = data });
}
```

I have a text file with the values

```
"DataSourceName"
"DataBaseName"
"User IDName"
"PasswordName"
```

And I want them in the connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Hotel" connectionString="DataSource="DataSourceName";Database="DatabaseName";User Id="UserIdName";Password="PasswordName""
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: So is your question how to read values from a text file, or how to build a connection string?

Comment: build a connection string, i know how to read the values but I don't know how to pass them to the connection string

Comment: Can you not use the XML config file in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using SqlClient, so: your best bet here is `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`:

```cs
var cb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(theBaseString);
cb.DataSource = dataSourceName;
cb.InitialCatalog = dataBaseName;
cb.UserID = userId;
cb.Password = password;
var connectionString = cb.ConnectionString;
```

If you don't have a template string (`theBaseString`), just use `new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()` instead.

The advantage of using `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` here is that it knows all about the escaping rules for non-trivial values, reserved characters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can format your connection string like below to pass the necessary values like **dbname** later.

```cs
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Hotel" connectionString="DataSource={0};Database={1};User Id={2};Password={3}"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

After that in your Helper class, return the formatted connection string with the values that you read from txt file.

```cs
public static string ConnectionString(string name)
    {
        var dataSourceName = "...";
        var dbName = "...";
        var userId = "...";
        var password = "...";

        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
        return string.Format(connectionString, dataSourceName, dbName, userId, password);
    }
```